# Set x.innerHTML as INPUT truncating value string

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
function edit(recRef)
{
var recID=recRef+'_what';
var x=document.getElementById(recID);
var y=(x.innerHTML);
alert(y);
x.innerHTML="<INPUT type='text' value="+y+" />";
}
```

The original recID element is a TD with a string in it [e.g. "This string"].

At the end of calling the edit function the an INPUT tag type text is inside the TD tag, but the string is truncated to only the first word [e.g. in the example it shows "This" but not "This string"].

Even more interesting, if the string in the TD was originally empty after calling edit the value on the INPUT tag is a single forward slash "/".

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
var recID = recRef+'_what';
var oRecord = document.getElementById(recID);
var sHTML = oRecord.innerHTML;
var oInput = document.createElement("input");
oInput.type = "text";
oInput.value = sHTML;
while (oRecord.childNodes.length > 0)
   oRecord.removeChild(oRecord.childNodes[0]);
oRecord.appendChild(oInput);
```

This will directly insert new DOM element instead of messing with the literal HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot ' in the value attribute

```
x.innerHTML="<INPUT type='text' value='"+y+"' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Built atop Shadow's response, heres what a cross browser solution might look like

```
function edit(recRef) {
    var isIE/*@cc_on=1@*/;
    var el = document.getElementById(recRef);
    var input = document.createElement( isIE ? "<input type='text'>" : "input" );
    input.setAttribute("value",el.innerHTML)
    el.replaceChild(input,el.childNodes[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - is it the case that the IE programmers wrote IE to return a true if isIE encountered while the other browser programs know nothing about it? [The /*@cc_on=1@*/ has got me curious[.

Comment: exactly, @cc_on represents conditional comment handling. only IE sets the value, all other browsers see isIE as undefined.